# How to Instantiate UIHostingController with CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, uihostingcontroller

As a long-time Obj-C dev (since iPhone OS 2) I decided that SwiftUI was the nudge to use Swift! ¯\*(ツ)*/¯
Thus, I am still trying to understand how a language can be so type-vague in code, and so type-pedantic in the compiler!!!

Pulling my hair out trying to get Swift/SwiftUI to instantiate a UIHostingController<>, for use with CoreData

```
class MyCoreDataHostingController : UIHostingController<MyCoreDataView> {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {//Instantiate From Storyboard
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let contentView = MyCoreDataView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: contentView)
        //Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'MyCoreDataView'
    }
}

struct MyCoreDataView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Core Data View")
    }
}
```

How can I FORCE Swift to INFER the correct/appropriate type?

What I have tried so far.

```
5 let contentView = MyCoreDataView()
```

Compiles/runs, but does not include CoreData.

```
6 super.init(coder: coder, rootView: contentView as! MyCoreDataView)
```

Compiles, but crashes at instantiation.

> Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<MyHostingController.MyCoreDataView, SwiftUI._EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<__C.NSManagedObjectContext>>' (...)
> to 'MyHostingController.MyCoreDataView' (...).

... or is this simply not possible? (yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fastest *come-in-mind* solution - just use `AnyView` type-eraser.

Note: any view modifier creates (can create in general) different type of view, that's why compiler complains in your case - types are different.

```
class MyCoreDataHostingController : UIHostingController<AnyView> {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {//Instantiate From Storyboard
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let contentView = MyCoreDataView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: AnyView(contentView))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posted by OOPer on Apple Dev Forums:

As you see, modifiers for SwiftUI View returns some opaque type some View which is not revealed to programmers but Swift compiler claims matching the type every here and there...

One possible solution is creating a wrapper View:

```
class MyCoreDataHostingController : UIHostingController<MyCoreDataViewEnvironmentWrapper> {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {//Instantiate From Storyboard
        let contentView = MyCoreDataViewEnvironmentWrapper()
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: contentView)
    }
}
struct MyCoreDataViewEnvironmentWrapper: View {
    private let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    var body: some View {
        MyCoreDataView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

Or you can choose AnyView as the wrapper:

```
class MyCoreDataHostingController : UIHostingController<AnyView> {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {//Instantiate From Storyboard
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let contentView = AnyView(MyCoreDataView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context))
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: contentView)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this works for your case, but please try.